# Alocating space in RAM, then creating and destroying different data structures here

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am wondering whether there is an efficient way of re-purposing space in RAM.

Let's say my function creates four different arrays and 10 of variables in dedicated space. Then some other function is called, that zeroes the allocated space and creates its own structure, that is different. What are my options? Is there a straight-forward way of doing it?

Comment: Do you mean writing your own memory allocator? Or what exactly is your question about? I find it rather unclear what you are asking

Comment: What i mean is how to create 'extern' variables, that can live outside the scope and be terminated by code. Can I do it with c++ struct, or do i need to write something full of pointers?

Comment: why not use a union?  does C++ not have unions?

Comment: What is the purpose? What is the problem with the standard mechanisms (local / global variables and `malloc`etc.)

Comment: @FeroFixxer: please **edit your question** don't comment it

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward way of doing it is using C. That's where this is "appropriate". In C++, don't.

In C++, the initialization function *goes* with the data type (known as constructor). And the allocation is done with `new`, or better yet, `new` is done by a container (such as a vector or a smart pointer).

Example:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7724d9eceae469c)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct MyData {
    int value;
    std::string name;

    MyData() : value(0), name("") 
    { }

    ~MyData() {
        if (!name.empty()) {
            std::cout << "The element with name " << name << " is being destructed\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MyData> v(100); // allocates 100 MyData instances, all initialized to `0, ""`

    v[5].value = 5;
    v[5].name = "Five";

} // here, all of the vector is destructed and memory is correctly "de-allocated" (freed).
```

Prints:

```
The element with name Five is being destructed
```

### Summary

The "automation" you see above is what makes C++ C++. It's a better language¹ with abstractions that make it so that you don't have to do all the work (and make it correct).

¹ objectively, compared to C. Of course, it can be used wrong, but the same goes for all languages.

Comment: You can always use placement new and call the destructor directly

Comment: @doron sure. That might be the most UN straightforward way though :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't allocate (at least on ordinary operating systems like Linux, Windows, MacOSX, etc...) in (physical) [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory), you allocate in [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) with [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) use by [standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_library) allocating functions (e.g. `malloc` in C, `operator new` in  C++). Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more about OSes.

<sup>On Linux, read about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and try `cat /proc/self/maps`, `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/$$/smaps` to understand more about virtual address space. The main syscall to increase the virtual address space is [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).</sup>

If you want to reuse in C++ some existing and valid address for a new (or another) data structure, you'll use the *placement `new`* operator. Read more about [`operator new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). You probably want to call some destructor before reusing the space used by some object. Read also about [union types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union), [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) and [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Be aware of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) programming idiom and of the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Don't be shy to use pointers. In C++, prefer [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) most of the time. Learn more about the [`<memory>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).